# How to pass a real plus character in string-values of JSON in the url hash fragment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url, single-page-application

I have a JS (Angular) app which loads parameters from the url fragment (after the # hash sign) - and the parameter contains json objects - like

`...#filters={"Course":["ST_12.+13.12.2016 [Basel]"]}`

The purpose is to open a data-grid and pre-filter some of the data - so the object is fairly generic.

The trouble is that any string like this is converted to

`filters=%7B%22Course%22:%5B%22ST_12.+13.12.2016+%5BBasel%5D%22%5D%7D`

which on reading in the target system is regarded as

`...#filters={"Course":["ST_12. 13.12.2016 [Basel]"]}`

So it loses the + and turns it into a space. The obvious solution would be to encode the + character as %2b, like

`filters=%7B%22Course%22:%5B%22ST_12.%2B13.12.2016+%5BBasel%5D%22%5D%7D`

but this fails. The moment you type this into a browser (chrome / firefox) the %2b is immediately decoded back into a + directly in the URL field - resulting in the original problem again.

I also searched the web and all answers I found discuss beginner questions why a space must be + encoded etc, but that's not what I'm concerned about. i really need to pass a normal string-value containing real text, incl. + characters reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `window.decodeURIComponent()`? I can decode the string using the `decodeURIComponent()` and it returns the correct format, with the + and everything you had encoded.

Comment: this doesn't work - the browsers convert all + and %2b into + in the url - so after a decode they are all spaces, no more +

Comment: can you provide more information on how to replicate the problem, what browser you are using, etc? maybe an example on jsfiddle

Comment: if you `decodeURIComponent()` on `#filters=%7B%22Course%22:%5B%22ST_12.+13.12.2016+%5BBasel%5D%22%5D%7D` it outputs `#filters={"Course":["ST_12.+13.12.2016+[Basel]"]}`. i can't find/replicate your problem

Comment: Your example only works in the console - where %2b is preserved. If you put that into the url run in through decodeUriComponent, the %2b after the hash will already have been converted to a + so that's when it fails, because decodeUriComponent sees a +, not a %2b, and turns it into a space